# Should I use shared Session in http requests in Python?

Tags: python, http, python-requests

I am calling a http service hosted by others and my code is the below:

```
def process_text(text):
    session = requests.Session()
    retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
    adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
    session.mount('http://', adapter)
    session.mount('https://', adapter)

    try:
        r = session.get(HTTP_URL, params={'text': text})
       
        r_json = r.json()
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error('Failed to request from http service: {}'.format(str(e)))
        return None
```

I have a text file that contains a lot of sentences and for each sentence, I need to call the 'process_text' function for each sentence. My question is, can I create one 'session' object only outside of the process_text like below:

```
class Processor(object):
   def __init__(self):
        self.session = requests.Session()
        retry = Retry(connect=3, backoff_factor=0.5)
        adapter = HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retry)
        self.session.mount('http://', adapter)
        self.session.mount('https://', adapter)

   def process_text(self.text):
       
    
        try:
            r = self.session.get(HTTP_URL, params={'text': text})
           
            r_json = r.json()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error('Failed to request from http service: {}'.format(str(e)))
            return None
```

Or the session has to be created for each individual request?

Comment: Yes one session can be used for all requests. Why don’t you just try it.

Comment: Reusing the session object is preferred, see [Session Objects](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects]. _So if you’re making several requests to the same host, the underlying TCP connection will be reused, which can result in a significant performance increase_